# Application_Error() not being called if Middleware throws an exception

Tags: owin, nancy

I originally had an IIS hosted Nancy application which had a custom error page *Errors\500.html*. Inside the *Errors* folder I had a *Web.config* file that removed the Nancy handler so that the error pages could be served.

There were two types of errors that I handled:

1. An error while initializing the Nancy Framework or a Nancy module would be handled by `Application_Error()` in *Global.asax*.
2. Any error while running a Nancy route would be handled by a custom Nancy `IStatusCodeHandler` implementation.

After switching to using **Nancy.Owin** `Application_Error()` is no being longer called.

I have tried a few variations of `Configuration()` in *Startup.cs* such as:

```
app.UseNancy(options => options.PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
```

But I cannot get `Application_Error()` to be called.

I have tried creating a custom middleware to handle the exception, but this only works for exceptions while running a route and not if there is a problem loading a Nancy module:

```
app.UseNancy(options => options.PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
app.Use<MyCustomExceptionMiddleware>();
```

---

How can I get my custom error pages loading (preferably still using `Application_Error()`)?

Using Nancy 0.22.2, Owin 1.0 and Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Application_Error() is not called when using OWIN.

Comment: It seems to get called if you are using ASP (Katana) and Owin. My question really boils down to, How can I get my custom error pages loading (preferably still using Application_Error())?